# Set ngModel if an object is returning true

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

Is it possible to revert the `[(ngModel)]` of an input text box to the previous value and set the `[(ngModel)]` only if an object returns `true`

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="textValue">
```

How can the value be dynamically set for `[(ngModel)]`?

Comment: What is "an object"? The input text or another property?

Comment: Suppose I'm entering value to input box on submit click i found some error so i want to set the value of model object to previous value

Comment: please clarify "some error"

Comment: suppose I had entered an invalid postal code by editing the previously entered correct postal code so in such a case i needed to revert the ngModel value to the previous value of ngModel...
@dince12 i think the answer u provided will work :)

Comment: Any other suggestions let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a ternary to check the value is true, the code below would use it if it is true or use another value if textValue is false. Below would be a small example, change accordingly to meet your requirements.

```
public originalValue = 'hello';
public textValue;  //may be truthy or falsy.

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="textValue ? textValue : originalValue">
```

break down of ternary. If the value to the left of the ? is truthy then the value after the question mark will be used. If the value before the ? is falsy then value after the : will be used.

For mentioned in the comments using above public variables. This would assume you had a function that tells you is postcode is valid or not returning true or false.

```
public submitFunction(): void
{
    const valueToUse = isPostCode(this.textValue) ? this.textValue : this.originalValue;
}
```